# How to register open generic type by interface with Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm trying to make this registration work. I have a number of `IEventFactory<>` responsible for creating different (external) events within my application.

I'd like to resolve all kinds of factories just by it's interface, eg `IEventFactory<ClassA>`. How do I make my test below succeed?

```
[TestFixture]
public class WindsorTests
{ 

    [Test]
    public void Test_factory_registration()
    {           

        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof(IEventFactory<>)).WithService.AllInterfaces());

        IEventFactory<ClassA> factoryA = container.Resolve<IEventFactory<ClassA>>();
        IEventFactory<ClassB> factoryB = container.Resolve<IEventFactory<ClassB>>();

    }


    class ClassA
    {

    }

    class ClassB
    {

    }


    interface IEventFactory<TCaller>
    {
        void Foo();
    }


    class EventFactoryA : IEventFactory<ClassA>
    {

        public void Foo()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class EventFactoryB : IEventFactory<ClassB>
    {

        public void Foo()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interfaces and factories are private.  Either make them public/internal or add `IncludeNonPublicTypes()` in the registration line.

Comment: Thank you! So simple. I just had them private in my test case :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Patrick Steele said, you probably also should be using `.WithService.Base()`

Have a look [at the documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Selecting_service_for_the_component_15) which details the differences.